How to add a column on a Pandas DataFrame that is based on the continent a country is
What I wanted to do is basically add a column of for all 7 continents, and I want the continents to be assigned based on where the country is located. Adding the column is the easy part, all I have to do is make a dictionary and turn it into a column of said Pandas DataFrame, the hard part is getting it to assign said continents to the DataFrame, which I tried searching online but so far I haven't found any solution.
So far I tried to search other solutions, however I couldn't find any that were related via mapping. They seemed far too tedious to type out, as I would have to type out every single country in order for the continent mapping to work. Example:
How to replace dataframe columns country name with continent?
BTW here is the file I used for the DataFrame:
https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/deeplyft/world-population-growth-annual
Any help would be appreciated in order to make it less tedious.

I would map the continents from the country codes. This is easily achieved using existing python libraries such as pycountry-convert that depends on robust data (from Debian's pkg-isocodes).
For this you can first craft a dictionary to perform a conversion between the codes ALPHA3 -> ALPHA2 -> CONTINENT_CODE -> CONTINENT_NAME
# !pip install pycountry-convert

import pycountry
from pycountry_convert.convert_country_alpha2_to_continent_code import COUNTRY_ALPHA2_TO_CONTINENT_CODE
from pycountry_convert.convert_continent_code_to_continent_name import CONTINENT_CODE_TO_CONTINENT_NAME

alpha3_to_continent = {x.alpha_3: CONTINENT_CODE_TO_CONTINENT_NAME.get(
                         COUNTRY_ALPHA2_TO_CONTINENT_CODE.get(x.alpha_2)
                       ) for x in pycountry.countries}

df['continent'] = df['country_code'].map(alpha3_to_continent)
# move the column before the years for clarity (optional)
df.insert(2, 'continent', df.pop('continent'))

Output:
                  country_name country_code      continent      1961      1962      1963      1964      1965      1966      1967      1968      1969      1970      1971      1972      1973      1974      1975      1976      1977      1978      1979      1980       1981       1982      1983      1984      1985      1986      1987      1988      1989      1990      1991       1992       1993      1994      1995      1996      1997      1998      1999      2000      2001      2002      2003      2004      2005      2006      2007      2008      2009      2010      2011      2012      2013      2014      2015      2016      2017      2018      2019      2020      2021      2022
0                        Aruba          ABW  North America  2.179059  1.548572  1.389337  1.215721  1.032841  0.862184  0.388847 -0.085719 -0.237372 -0.378264 -0.491852  0.066287  0.862804  1.110629  1.137966  0.784202  0.443510  0.443172  0.433153  0.420044   0.555730   0.798541  0.894335  0.768049  0.472594  0.116251 -0.159686 -0.183255  0.409531  1.712907  3.222415   3.372864   3.041932  3.196029  3.084061  3.025789  3.027359  3.004805  2.934413  2.539234  1.768757  1.194718  0.997396  0.900989  1.003077  1.181566  1.227711  1.241397  1.233231  1.131541  0.939356  0.810231  0.749301  0.691615  0.637959  0.590062  0.537296  0.494795  0.451970  0.134255 -0.045045 -0.086392
1  Africa Eastern and Southern          AFE            NaN  2.660180  2.732633  2.753248  2.806915  2.840787  2.813609  2.830505  2.881589  2.898532  2.911526  2.914856  2.870881  2.903938  2.986296  2.982409  2.969810  2.884096  3.012733  3.142594  2.965406   3.017564   3.130762  3.012801  2.939088  2.970293  3.022264  3.062817  2.919182  2.844888  2.911013  2.792410   2.633682   2.658526  2.619955  2.627107  2.693098  2.580384  2.514654  2.559662  2.583579  2.589961  2.606598  2.617764  2.644968  2.666242  2.702521  2.747109  2.765816  2.755745  2.757929  2.738185  2.740405  2.780207  2.774990  2.802586  2.728159  2.655672  2.688371  2.691134  2.678184  2.607472  2.543757
2                  Afghanistan          AFG           Asia  1.925952  2.014879  2.078997  2.139651  2.216007  2.253524  2.292638  2.347351  2.378917  2.433183  2.415369  2.429396  2.524421  2.513007  2.393287  2.179517  2.086951  1.963377  0.366493 -3.924172 -11.275324 -10.053006 -1.365708  2.894335  2.587697 -0.608561 -1.210190  0.586318  2.751877  0.202434  0.469880  11.522524  14.964455  9.864262  6.046536  4.103022  3.910605  3.882931  4.077879  1.443803  0.742517  6.449321  7.541019  3.933178  3.576508  4.139678  1.793196  2.002333  3.561288  2.894904  3.689508  4.077628  3.466788  3.657576  3.121341  2.581549  2.866492  2.885208  2.908529  3.134747  2.851358  2.534498
3   Africa Western and Central          AFW            NaN  2.115789  2.145723  2.190827  2.211360  2.242567  2.272816  2.275721  2.295953  2.323998  2.368198  2.397568  2.435340  2.511747  2.597047  2.683551  2.697073  2.735732  2.814038  2.850410  2.845011   2.849794   2.895500  2.720131  2.615809  2.705308  2.711539  2.713602  2.731061  2.766998  2.654931  2.628369   2.730421   2.671363  2.630610  2.693235  2.687499  2.689029  2.721941  2.706291  2.749600  2.799654  2.811453  2.816481  2.828642  2.841211  2.832780  2.828409  2.832916  2.844037  2.846536  2.848826  2.812851  2.761839  2.750731  2.723317  2.713059  2.706266  2.669239  2.633982  2.615646  2.573377  2.539799
4                       Angola          AGO         Africa  1.558355  1.460738  1.410425  1.301745  1.111041  0.875806  0.696698  0.695985  1.020355  1.694526  2.414339  2.993132  3.299374  3.352360  3.328324  3.274073  3.317449  3.398701  3.435448  3.503985   3.554422   3.592195  3.617137  3.609872  3.603751  3.565856  3.438674  3.367043  3.371351  3.345144  3.326137   3.248850   3.161547  3.198433  3.289676  3.330132  3.335154  3.279068  3.226448  3.244121  3.285217  3.335132  3.413321  3.506389  3.557659  3.592013  3.639589  3.670909  3.693482  3.734798  3.758796  3.758703  3.735525  3.684429  3.617678  3.586211  3.550987  3.464457  3.395278  3.268348  3.166030  3.096753

However your dataset does not only include countries, but also non-official regions such as "Africa Western and Central" or "Africa Western and Central", for those you could extract the continent name from the string:
import re

pat = '(%s)' % '|'.join(map(re.escape, CONTINENT_CODE_TO_CONTINENT_NAME.values()))
# '(Asia|Europe|North\\ America|South\\ America|Africa|Oceania|Antarctica)'

m = df['continent'].isna()
df.loc[m, 'continent'] = df.loc[m, 'country_name'].str.extract(pat, expand=False)

Output:
                 country_name country_code      continent      1961      1962      1963      1964      1965      1966      1967      1968      1969      1970      1971      1972      1973      1974      1975      1976      1977      1978      1979      1980       1981       1982      1983      1984      1985      1986      1987      1988      1989      1990      1991       1992       1993      1994      1995      1996      1997      1998      1999      2000      2001      2002      2003      2004      2005      2006      2007      2008      2009      2010      2011      2012      2013      2014      2015      2016      2017      2018      2019      2020      2021      2022
0                        Aruba          ABW  North America  2.179059  1.548572  1.389337  1.215721  1.032841  0.862184  0.388847 -0.085719 -0.237372 -0.378264 -0.491852  0.066287  0.862804  1.110629  1.137966  0.784202  0.443510  0.443172  0.433153  0.420044   0.555730   0.798541  0.894335  0.768049  0.472594  0.116251 -0.159686 -0.183255  0.409531  1.712907  3.222415   3.372864   3.041932  3.196029  3.084061  3.025789  3.027359  3.004805  2.934413  2.539234  1.768757  1.194718  0.997396  0.900989  1.003077  1.181566  1.227711  1.241397  1.233231  1.131541  0.939356  0.810231  0.749301  0.691615  0.637959  0.590062  0.537296  0.494795  0.451970  0.134255 -0.045045 -0.086392
1  Africa Eastern and Southern          AFE         Africa  2.660180  2.732633  2.753248  2.806915  2.840787  2.813609  2.830505  2.881589  2.898532  2.911526  2.914856  2.870881  2.903938  2.986296  2.982409  2.969810  2.884096  3.012733  3.142594  2.965406   3.017564   3.130762  3.012801  2.939088  2.970293  3.022264  3.062817  2.919182  2.844888  2.911013  2.792410   2.633682   2.658526  2.619955  2.627107  2.693098  2.580384  2.514654  2.559662  2.583579  2.589961  2.606598  2.617764  2.644968  2.666242  2.702521  2.747109  2.765816  2.755745  2.757929  2.738185  2.740405  2.780207  2.774990  2.802586  2.728159  2.655672  2.688371  2.691134  2.678184  2.607472  2.543757
2                  Afghanistan          AFG           Asia  1.925952  2.014879  2.078997  2.139651  2.216007  2.253524  2.292638  2.347351  2.378917  2.433183  2.415369  2.429396  2.524421  2.513007  2.393287  2.179517  2.086951  1.963377  0.366493 -3.924172 -11.275324 -10.053006 -1.365708  2.894335  2.587697 -0.608561 -1.210190  0.586318  2.751877  0.202434  0.469880  11.522524  14.964455  9.864262  6.046536  4.103022  3.910605  3.882931  4.077879  1.443803  0.742517  6.449321  7.541019  3.933178  3.576508  4.139678  1.793196  2.002333  3.561288  2.894904  3.689508  4.077628  3.466788  3.657576  3.121341  2.581549  2.866492  2.885208  2.908529  3.134747  2.851358  2.534498
3   Africa Western and Central          AFW         Africa  2.115789  2.145723  2.190827  2.211360  2.242567  2.272816  2.275721  2.295953  2.323998  2.368198  2.397568  2.435340  2.511747  2.597047  2.683551  2.697073  2.735732  2.814038  2.850410  2.845011   2.849794   2.895500  2.720131  2.615809  2.705308  2.711539  2.713602  2.731061  2.766998  2.654931  2.628369   2.730421   2.671363  2.630610  2.693235  2.687499  2.689029  2.721941  2.706291  2.749600  2.799654  2.811453  2.816481  2.828642  2.841211  2.832780  2.828409  2.832916  2.844037  2.846536  2.848826  2.812851  2.761839  2.750731  2.723317  2.713059  2.706266  2.669239  2.633982  2.615646  2.573377  2.539799
4                       Angola          AGO         Africa  1.558355  1.460738  1.410425  1.301745  1.111041  0.875806  0.696698  0.695985  1.020355  1.694526  2.414339  2.993132  3.299374  3.352360  3.328324  3.274073  3.317449  3.398701  3.435448  3.503985   3.554422   3.592195  3.617137  3.609872  3.603751  3.565856  3.438674  3.367043  3.371351  3.345144  3.326137   3.248850   3.161547  3.198433  3.289676  3.330132  3.335154  3.279068  3.226448  3.244121  3.285217  3.335132  3.413321  3.506389  3.557659  3.592013  3.639589  3.670909  3.693482  3.734798  3.758796  3.758703  3.735525  3.684429  3.617678  3.586211  3.550987  3.464457  3.395278  3.268348  3.166030  3.096753

That still leaves some entries unassigned:
print(df.loc[df['continent'].isna(), 'country_name'].tolist())

['Channel Islands', 'Caribbean small states', 'Early-demographic dividend', 'Euro area', 'IBRD only', 'IDA & IBRD total', 'IDA total', 'IDA blend', 'IDA only', 'Latin America & Caribbean (excluding high income)', 'Low & middle income', 'Late-demographic dividend', 'Pre-demographic dividend', 'Post-demographic dividend', 'Sint Maarten (Dutch part)', 'Latin America & the Caribbean (IDA & IBRD countries)', 'Timor-Leste', 'Kosovo', 'World', 'Small states', 'Pacific island small states', 'Other small states', 'OECD members', 'Least developed countries: UN classification', 'Latin America & Caribbean', 'Heavily indebted poor countries (HIPC)', 'Fragile and conflict affected situations', 'Arab World', 'Upper middle income', 'Middle income', 'Lower middle income', 'Low income', 'High income']

Some of which could be manually assigned to a continent ("Channel Islands" -> "Europe"), other could be ambiguous ('World') or not a geographic region ('Other small states', 'Late-demographic dividend').
For that you can add a last step with a custom mapper:
custom = {'Channel Islands': 'Europe'}
m = df['continent'].isna()
df.loc[m, 'continent'] = df.loc[m, 'country_name'].map(custom)


First create dictionary by all countries, e.g. from https://statisticstimes.com:
df1 = pd.read_html('https://statisticstimes.com/geography/countries-by-continents.php')[2]
print (df1.head())
   No Country or Area ISO-alpha3 Code  M49 Code         Region 1 Region 2  \
0   1     Afghanistan             AFG         4    Southern Asia      NaN   
1   2   Åland Islands             ALA       248  Northern Europe      NaN   
2   3         Albania             ALB         8  Southern Europe      NaN   
3   4         Algeria             DZA        12  Northern Africa      NaN   
4   5  American Samoa             ASM        16        Polynesia      NaN   

  Continent  
0      Asia  
1    Europe  
2    Europe  
3    Africa  
4   Oceania 

#check continents
print (df1['Continent'].unique())
['Asia' 'Europe' 'Africa' 'Oceania' 'North America' 'Antarctica'
 'South America'] 

d = df1.set_index('Country or Area')['Continent'].to_dict()
# print (d)

Or from https://country-code.cl:
df1 = pd.read_html('https://country-code.cl/', encoding='iso-8859-1', skiprows=12)[1]
print (df1.head())
  Continent  Unnamed: 1            Name ISO 2 ISO 3 CIA Telephone Internet  \
0        AS         NaN     Afghanistan    AF   AFG  af        93      .af   
1        EU         NaN   Åland Islands    AX   ALA  fi    358 18      .ax   
2        EU         NaN         Albania    AL   ALB  al       355      .al   
3        AF         NaN         Algeria    DZ   DZA  ag       213      .dz   
4        OC         NaN  American Samoa    AS   ASM  aq     1 684      .as   

  Vehicle  
0     AFG  
1      AX  
2      AL  
3      DZ  
4     NaN 

di = {'AS':'Asia',
      'EU':'Europe',
      'AF':'Africa',
      'OC':'Oceania',
      'NA':'North America',
      'AN':'Antarctica',
      'SA':'South America'}

print (df1['Continent'].unique())
['AS' 'EU' 'AF' 'OC' nan 'AN' 'SA']

d = df1.set_index('Name')['Continent'].map(di).dropna().to_dict()
# print (d)

And then map column in your DataFrame, e.g.:
df['continent'] = df['country'].map(d)

